# Are USB A -> C / C -> A cables not the same for data?

Tags: usb

My specific situation is that I have a PC with only USB-A ports, and a monitor hub with a USB-C upstream port and USB-A downstream ports. I therefore need a male A male C cable (or a dongle).

Then I notice that manufacturers are very vague on how such cables can be used, eg. 
* A at "host", C at "device" (Delock)
* A at peripheral, C at "device" (Manhattan)
* No info but images suggest anything is possible (Ugreen)

It sounds like this has to do with power delivery. Is there anything to be aware of if I'm only interested in data transfer but don't need any charging- or display capability?

Regards

Comment: USB-C supports way more than any other USB port. USB-C can also do video, audio, files, ethernet, etc. This is why USB C to A is different than A to C.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is not specific, it is very basic, since you have a standard legacy USB host. The use of legacy cable assemblies is fully specified in Type-C connector specifications.

In very brief, there are two basic legacy cables for Type-A ports. First one is to connect the basic PC to a Type-C peripheral. The cable internals look like this one,

[image]

Note that the cable has PLUGS on both ends, so the Type-A end can go only to legacy USB host port (into Type-A receptacle). The legacy host has VBUS always on.

The device side of the cable must inform the target device that it is the host on the other side. Do do this, the cable overmold must have a pull-up resistor, with standard value of 56k, which indicates the standard USB port with 500mA/900mA driving capability. The data role direction is from Type-A host to Type-C device. This is the standard most common cable, and this is the one you should use in your "specific situation".

There could be a different kind of cable with Type-A-Type-C connectors, but it must have a Type-A **receptacle** on the left end:

[image]

This assembly is frequently called "OTG adapter". This assembly serves the opposite direction of data transfers, from Type-C host to Type-A port. If your PC would have the Type-C port, it can be a host or dual-role port. The pull-down 5.1k resistor serves as an indicator of the role and as a "cable connect". Without this pull-down the Type-C port won't enable VBUS out, and no communication would occur.

These are only the two UBS-legal cable assemblies, anything else is wrong.